# Aiogram как вернутся на первый state

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как, находясь на последнем этапе машины состояний, вернуться на первый шаг(State).
Eсть ли какая-нибудь функция по аналогии `FSMContext.next()`, только для возвращения на первый шаг, например с 4 шага.

Answer (score 0):

```
reset_state(*, chat: typing.Union[str, int, NoneType] = None, user: typing.Union[str, int, NoneType] = None, with_data: typing.Union[bool, NoneType] = True)
```

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev/dispatcher/storage.html#aiogram.dispatcher.storage.BaseStorage.reset_state

мб это поможет

Comment: Не, эта штука сбрасывает стейт на `None`. А еще ссылка умерла

Answer (score 0):

Ну так просто задай это состояние как ты делал это в первый раз.
К примеру

```
class Pool(StatesGroup):
    state1 = State()
    state2 = State()

# и в хендлере/функции делаешь вот так
Pool.state1.set()
```

Просто вот так и меняй стейт

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeStates(StatesGroup):
    state1=State()
    state2=State()
    state3=State()
    state4=State()


@dp.message_handler()
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # ...some logic
    await SomeStates.state1.set()
```

Нужно вызвать метод set у стадии, которая вам нужная, остальную логику aiogram сделает под капотом.